# Error when Opening Mantra Security Browser on OSX

Tags: browser, osx-lion, firefox, cocoadialog

Okay, this is puzzling me. When opening Mantra Toolkit Browser on my 10.7 Lappy, I get this:

> You can't open the application CocoaDialog because PowerPC applications are no longer supported.

I googled the phrase as many ways as I could think, and can't find a solution. The program opens fine, but that dialog is annoying. Any ideas ya'll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mantra Security Browser includes a PowerPC-only version of [cocoaDialog](http://mstratman.github.com/cocoadialog/). 10.7 does no longer support those using Rosetta.

[image: Location of CocoaDialog in the Mantra application bundle]

It is used to display rather useless Growl-style notification windows.

[image: Program start notification] [image: Program exit notification]

You can replace the bundled, PowerPC-only version of cocoaDialog with the download from its website to get those informative messages. Just download cocoaDialog 2.1.1 from its website, right-click the Mantra application bundle, select *Show Package Contents*, navigate to the location shown in the Finder screenshot above, and replace the `CocoaDialog.app`.